# How to terminate TimerThread in Timer

Tags: java, timer

When I read the source code of `java.util.Timer` , I found that `java.util.Timer` is implemented by a `TimerThread` and a `TaskQueue`

It is said that `java.util.Timer` can be cancelled by `java.util.Timer.cancel()`,

But when I call `java.util.Timer.cancel()` I found TimerThread in Timer still running ,

Does this a problem for online system ?

And if possible , how can I stop `TimerThread` inside `java.util.Timer`?

---

From source of `TimerThread` (jdk 7) I finally found that `Timer.cancel()` do works.

TimerThread *wait* `TaskQueue` , when `Timer.cancel()` called , `TaskQueue` *notify* `TimerThread` ,  And TimerThead should finally exit if `TaskQueue is EMPTY...

Thank you for your comment , sorry to wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

Timer thread will still be running. But the timer thread will stop accepting anything into the queue as per the implementation.

The `timer`(TimerThread) thread is accessible to you only via `Timer` class. `TimerThread` is encapsultaed inside `Timer` class. Implementation wise, they have made sure the Timer stops accepting the requests to its queue, but the `TimerThread` as such is not stopped.

Comment: Does this a problem for online system ?

Comment: @LPD +1 I deleted my answer as it make no sense for `java.util.Timer` and you are right `java.util.Timer` uses `cancel()` method and `javax.swing.Timer` uses `stop()` method to stop timer.

Comment: @jackalope I defnitly don't understand why are you trying to terminate timer here? If it stopaccepting the entries to the queue isn't that enough?

Comment: Suppose I have a temp thread to run a procedure , in the procedure I create a `Timer` . Then I kill this thread , but the thread related by the `Timer` can't. SO In this case , I'm VERY worried about something bad would happen if I keep on create those temp thread.

Comment: When you kill the temp thread, the `Timer` object gets garbage collected, once that happens, `TimerThread` object present inside the `Timer` object will also be removed as there ll be no references for it.

Comment: @LPD but it's a running thread , are you sure GC will recycle a running thread?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, Yes it does. If you are not comfortable doing it I would then suggest another approach of creating a singleton class which HAS a timer, and make use of the same class.

Comment: After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection). However, this can take arbitrarily long to occur. By default, the task execution thread does not run as a daemon thread, so it is capable of keeping an application from terminating. If a caller wants to terminate a timer's task execution thread rapidly, the caller should invoke the timer's cancel method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Now please accept the answer if you found this discussion useful :P

Answer (score 1):

`Timer` is single thread which holds list of `Task` to execute, once all Task are executed suucessfully the `Timer` thread instance will called by `Garbage Collector` after some time

Comment: so will garbage collector recycle it ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...The section describes the reasons in some cases the timer thread doesn't end.

http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Comment: these Four way of terminating a timerthread provided in the document all can't solve my problem.