# Eclipse debugging issue - is it an issue of too many threads?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I recently ported a fairly large application from C# to Java. It ought to have about 6 main threads running and lots of timers being fired (but each executing only briefly). I make use of the Timer class and call myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { ...

Now that I'm at the end of the port, I'm having a problem debugging the application in Eclipse, especially lately. I set a breakpoint: Eclipse will hit it but I can't step through at that point. I don't think I can look at variable values or stack trace or anything.

I see my list of threads going crazy, and based on output statements I've written, I can see that Thread.activeCount() gets to be over 200 threads. I am curious as to whether this is my debugging problem. Have I overloaded Eclipse to the point that it goes crazy?

From the threads I can actually see, most of them are my Timers that have been run. Somewhere I read that the JVM will keep those alive even if you cancel them (?). Anyway, if it's including all of the timers I've fired then perhaps over 200 threads makes sense.

I did once today also see an Eclipse "out of memory" error.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Eclipse or your code? Hmmmm.....

Comment: Can show show a list or a screen shot of all the threads that Eclipse lists?

Comment: So, Eclipse is going so crazy that it generally can't seem to show me more than about 10-15 threads. But I can see the thread window continually resizing itself, and the thread window scroll bar goes really far down.

Comment: Other behavior: I set a breakpoint, and the code just doesn't stop there at all (but I know it's executing that code)

Comment: Also, the Thread.activeCount() that I'm printing to a log file is reaching over 400.

Comment: Without actually seeing your code, I'm going to guess you aren't properly closing your threads. It's not Eclipse's fault that you have hundreds of dangling threads...

Comment: Well, that's part of my question. I have all of these timer threads that have been fired. How do you close them? From this stackoverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985554/how-to-terminate-timerthread-in-timer it seems to me that the TimerThread does not get stopped even when you cancel it.